# Periods of Conjugates of Harmonic Measures

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Harmonic measures are introduced in *Ahlfors* as follows.

(Let $\Omega$ be a multiply connected region bounded by an outer contour $C_n$ and $n-1$ inner contours $C_1, \dots , C_{n-1}$.) Suppose now that we solve the Dirichlet problem in $\Omega$ with the boundary values 1 on $C_k$ and 0 on the other contours. The solution is denoted by $\omega_k(z)$, and it is called the harmonic measure of $C_k$ with respect to the region $\Omega$. We have clearly $0 < \omega_k(z) < 1$ in $\Omega$ and

$$\omega_1(z) + \omega_2(z) + \cdots + \omega_n(z) = 1.$$

The contours $C_1, \dots , C_{n-1}$ form a homology basis for the cycles in $\Omega$, homology being understood with respect to an unspecified larger region. The conjugate harmonic differential of $\omega_k$ has periods

$$\alpha_{kj} = \int_{C_j}\frac{\partial \omega_k}{\partial n} ds =\int_{C_j} *d\omega_k$$

along $C_j$.

As an exercise, we are asked to do the following.

**Prove that $\alpha_{ij}=\alpha_{ji}$. Hint: Apply Theorem 21, Chap. 4.**

Below is Theorem 21, Chap. 4.

Theorem 21. A nonconstant harmonic function has neither a maximum nor a minimum in its region of definition. Consequently, the maximum and the minimum on a closed bounded set $E$ are taken on the boundary of $E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I realized that *Theorem 21* in the hint is probably a typo. The solution is quite obvious if we use Theorem 19 instead.

**Theorem 19.** If $u_1$ and $u_2$ are harmonic in a region $\Omega$, then

$$\int_\gamma u_1 \textrm{ }^\ast du_2 - u_2 \textrm{ }^\ast du_1 = 0$$

for every cycle $\gamma$ which is homologous to zero in $\omega$.

Since $\omega_i(z)$ has value 1 on $C_i$ and 0 on $C_j$ where $j \neq i$, we have

$$\int_{C_1 + C_2 + \cdots + C_n} \omega_i \textrm{ }^\ast d\omega_j - \omega_j \textrm{ }^\ast d\omega_i = \int_{C_i} \textrm{ }^\ast d\omega_j - \int_{C_j} \textrm{ }^\ast d\omega_i = 0, $$

which is what we need to prove.